# C# Access user folder in Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp

For Windows Vista and up, the user folder `C:\Users\MyUser` the folder is accessed programatically like this

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%userprofile%\");
```

How do I access the user folder in XP? Like this

`C:\Documents and Settings\MyUser\`

EDIT: I am using Framework 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `SpecialFolder` enumeration (.Net 4)

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
```

Comment: I actually need the Application Data folder in the User profile, will your code work with .ApplicationData at the end?

Comment: `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` is not shown as being limited to V4 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: what do you mean not shown, I just tried it in the code and it compiles

Comment: @GrantWinney what about the Local Settings folder in User, how do I access it?